# Postion on date in table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like:

```
EmiDate    | EmiAmt | PaidDate   | PaidAmt 
-----------+--------+------------+--------
2019-01-05 | 7500   | 2019-01-05 | 7500
2019-01-06 | 7500   | 2019-01-06 | 7500
2019-01-07 | 7500   | null       | null
2019-01-08 | 7500   | 2019-05-08 | 6500
2019-01-09 | 7500   | null       | null
2019-01-10 | 7500   | null       | null
```

I want to get `SUM(EmiAmt)` and `SUM(PaidAmt)` on date "2019-07-31". Result should look like:

```
22500 | 15000
```

My try is:

```
SELECT SUM(EmiAmt)
     , CASE WHEN PaidDate <= '2019-07-01' THEN SUM(PaidAmt) END
  FROM tbl_Emi
 WHERE EMIDate <= '2019-07-31';
```

which gives me error of 'non-aggregated column'.

Comment: Put the `case` expression inside the `sum()` instead.

Comment: `2019-07-31` and `01-05-2019` are 2 different date formats. Can those 2 be compared at all? @jarlh

Comment: @B001ᛦ, I wouldn't expect that. (Unless it's a character column, and the comparisons will execute, but giving an invalid result...)

Comment: Is your columns `EmiDate` & `PaidDate` are in `date` datatype or `string` datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you find below

```
select sum(EmiAmt),  sum(case when PaidDate  <='2019-07-01' then  PaidAmt else 0 end )
from tbl_Emi
where EMIDate <='2019-07-31';
```